# Use SCP command on Windows gitlab runner

Tags: command, gitlab, scp, gitlab-ci-runner

In my `gitlab-ci.yml`, i wrote :

```
deploy:
    stage: build
    script:
        - scp target/ROOT.war user@host/data/temp
```

But my Windows GitLab-ci runner throws an error :

> `scp` is not recognized as an internal or external command

Do you know if it's possible to add `scp` package to the runner or something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scp.exe` is packaged with any of the [latest distribution of Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases):

```
vonc@VONCAVN7 C:\Users\vonc
> where scp
D:\prgs\git\latest\usr\bin\scp.exe
```

If your GitLab agent has in its `%PATH%` the `<installation path of Git>/usr/bin`, it will have `scp`.

The [OP GGO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8126658/ggo) details [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708879/use-scp-command-on-windows-gitlab-runner/48716805?noredirect=1#comment84569374_48716805):

> In fact I added the git `/usr/bin` path in system path var (and not user path var) and recreated my runner instead of using `set` command.
>   It works!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and it was a good idea but i stil have the same error while `scp` command works in any command windows. I think Gitlab runner executes commands in a docker and doesn't have access to parent windows commands

Comment: @GGO Simply echo the PATH to check what the Git*lab-ci runner is working with, and adjust said path accordingly.

Comment: you're right, I don't have same `%PATH%` in window command than runner commands. Is missing many folders, how can i change it in runner ?

Comment: @GGO With a `before_script` directive: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1249

Comment: Doest not works too : `export is not recognized as an internal or external command`.

Comment: Sure, don't use export. 9n Windows, use set

Comment: Ok, in fact i added the git `/usr/bin` path in system `path` var (and not user path var) and recreated my runner instead of using `set` command. It works ! Thanks ! Can you edit your answer with this information and i will accept ?

Comment: @GGO Thank you. I have updated the answer accordingly.